# Access org.aspectj.weaver.Advice

Tags: aspectj

Is it possible to get all org.aspectj.weaver.Advice or Aspect Objects from the AspectJ Framework?
If it is, how?

I dont't want to deal with Reflections, because I have to parse everything and it's very errorprone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you want to do? Why do you think you need those objects? And what is your AspectJ experience level? Your other question about LTW + ITD suggests you want to do a lot of hacky things. Maybe there are simpler ways to solve your problems. Or are you just playing around?

Comment: I want to use these Objects to match method objects i gathered via reflection out of MethodHandle objects. If the pointcuts match i want to wrap the advices around these MethodHandle objects. You're right it is very hacky. Actually it works more or less with the aspectj reflection api, but i think it would be faster, smarter and easier if I can use the original weaver objects with an aspectj extension or some other api.

Comment: Maybe I had one cocktail too many tonight, but I still have no idea what you intend to do. Maybe code examples would help me help you. Edit: My problem is that it sounds like you want to do something manually which AspectJ LTW already does for you: match pointcuts and weave advice.

Comment: Okay it's right that I reimplement some functionality of the aspectj weaver. The reason for this is I want to match invokedynamic method calls. Actually that's not possible, thus I am writing a wrapper capable of doing this. I weave the MethodHandles of matching advices directly into the JoinPoint MethodHandle. I hope this makes my intention a little bit more comprehensible. The question aims to reduce the reimplementation overhead that comes with the reflection api.

Comment: Sorry if I am mentioning something obvious which might not be applicable to your situation, but how about using `execution` pointcuts instead of `call`? This way code called via `invokedynamic` can be intercepted.

Comment: Maybe you can ask Andy Clement about the status of https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364886.

Comment: Right, the execution pointcuts are working, but it's my thesis to write some kind of extention for call pointcuts supporting invokedynamic methods. At the moment it is in form of a wrapper relying on reflection. But I wonder if there's a better way to use the aspectj functions. I have already searched and found nothing.

Comment: Are you the guy who won this job? https://www.fachschaft.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=483&t=24723

Comment: Yes, I am. But we discarted the idea of extending the aspect bench compiler.